# How to set large icon for GCM notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In `GCM 3.0` notification when the app is in background will be handled by `GCM SDK` itself. But I am Unable to set the Large icon the the notification created when the app is in background.

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "great match!",
        "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "icon" : "myicon"
    }
}
```

The `myicon` sent here is displayed as the small icon.

Is it possible to set large icon for notification when the app is in background?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating to use `FCM` and Firebase for notifications but if you are using `GCM` right now I assume you have a registered receiver class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`.  In there you should override `onReceive` so you can construct and display the notification however you like.

The official docs on notifications explain all the options including setting the large icon [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

There's also some sample code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java).

Answer (score 0):

You can set large icon for your Notification using `setLargeIcon()` method while you are building notification.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
............................
.............................

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(job_title))

            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```